# Event Sourcing in F#: what if aggregate state must be updated between events production?

Tags: f#, event-sourcing

I just started diving into F# language and recently read an [article](https://medium.com/@dzoukr/event-sourcing-step-by-step-in-f-be808aa0ca18) about Event Sourcing in functional style and have some questions to clarify. There was the following  command handler presented:

```
let execute state command =     
    let event = 
        match command with    
        | AddTask args -> 
            args.Id 
            |> onlyIfTaskDoesNotAlreadyExist state 
            |> (fun _ -> TaskAdded args)    
        | RemoveTask args -> 
            args.Id 
            |> onlyIfTaskExists state 
            |> (fun _ -> TaskRemoved args)    
        | ClearAllTasks -> AllTasksCleared    
        | CompleteTask args -> 
            args.Id 
            |> onlyIfTaskExists state 
            |> (fun _ -> TaskCompleted args)    
        | ChangeTaskDueDate args -> 
            args.Id 
            |> (onlyIfTaskExists state >> onlyIfNotAlreadyFinished)
            |> (fun _ -> TaskDueDateChanged args)
    event |> List.singleton //we must return list of events
```

It's pretty simple when one command produces one event. But how to deal with case when state of the aggregate must be updated before some newer events will be produced?

Consider the following example: you have an **Order** aggregate and an **OrderLine** entity inside it. User can add or remove order lines and every time he did this order's total sum must be calculated. It can be implemented by three functions:

```
let addOrderLine order catalogItem = if (isOpen order) then Ok OrderLineAdded(catalogItem .Id, catalogItem.Price) else Error OrderAlreadyClosed

let removeOrderLine order lineId = if (isOpen order) then Ok OrderLineRemoved(lineId)  else Error OrderAlreadyClosed

let calculateOrder order = 
       let sum = order.orderLines |> List.sum (fun x -> x.Price)
       OrderCalculated sum
```

So **caculateOrder** function should be invoked only with actual aggregate's state. That means I need to add order line first, update state with produced **OrderLineAdded** event and finally execute calculation. After all I will collect all of events produced and return them from handler. It would be very easy to implement such case in OOP style but in FP handler grows in size incredibly fast. It seems like design smell to me.

Should I rethink my design and join **OrderLineAdded** and **OrderCalculated** events in one? Or here can be some elegant solution hidded from my eyes?

Any suggestions are welcome

### EDIT

I will add a C# implementation, which doesn't make me question. OOP aggregate is a mutable object, you can update its status easily, what is not functional programming way

```
public sealed class Order: EventSourcedAggregate
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    
    public bool isOpen { get; private set; }
    public decimal TotalSum { get; private set; }
    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; }
    public void Apply(OrderLineAdded e) { OrderLines.Add(new OrderLine(e.Id, e.Price));}
    public void Apply(OrderCalculated e) { TotalSum = e.Sum;}

    public void AddOrderLine(CatalogItem item)
    {
        if (!isOpen) throw new InvalidOperationException("Order closed exception");
        Emit(new OrderLineAdded(item.Id, item.Price)); //Emit method saves event as uncommitted and updates aggregate state
        CalculateOrder();                                   //calculates total sum 
    }

    private void CalculateOrder()
    {
        var sum = OrderLines.Sum(x => x.Price);
        Emit(new OrderCalculated(sum));
    }
}
```

Comment: Another thought: you can also let go of the constraint and handle the events as they come. If the user decides to checkout, wait for a order calculated that corresponds with the orderlines currently in the basket (pass a copy of what order is calculated).

Comment: The sum is an aggregate and calculated  when needed. If you want as an event why not just calculate it at the same time? Why would it be a separate thing?

Comment: I would be grateful to receive general advice, beyond the scope of the current example. Maybe it was inaccurate a bit. Yes, i can calculate sum other way, but i want to know what should i do in situation when aggregate needs to be updated few times while handler executes command. Is it viable solution to use cqrs+event sourcing this way or not? When viable, how to handle such situation in F#? When not, which drawbacks it provides?

Comment: Command -> State -> Events. So everything you decide inside of a command handler should only be recorded as events. The aggregate is consequence of the events.

Comment: So updating the aggregate inside of the command handler doesn’t make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not an F# dev by any means, so will answer this in Scala.

Remember that you have the event-handling function available (because your aggregate is defined by the pair of the event handler and the command handler):

```scala
val eventHandler: Event => Aggregate => Aggregate = ???  // ??? meaning "not implemented yet, but we know the type it'll be
```

This does imply that every event, given a handler, is isomorphic to a function from `Aggregate` to `Aggregate`, which is the most interesting FP interpretation of events (IMO).

So in a command handler, if one for some reason wants the state of the aggregate after applying an event one need only apply the event handler themselves

```scala
val commandHandler: Aggregate => Command => (Response, Seq[Event]) = state => cmd => {
  cmd match {
    case AddOrderLine(catalogId, price) =>
      if (!isOpen(state)) Error(OrderAlreadyClosed) -> Seq.empty
      else {
        val added = OrderLineAdded(catalogId, price)
        val intermediateState = eventHandler(added)(state)
        // explicit iterator to not create an intermediate strict collection
        val sum = intermediateState.orderLines.iterator.map(_.price).sum
        Ok -> Seq(added, OrderCalculated(sum))
      }
  }
}
```

Of course, there's no reason the event handler for `OrderLineAdded` couldn't update the sum.  Part of the benefit of event sourcing is that your events can designate changes to arbitrarily many properties of an aggregate (a model that has a command and a corresponding event for changing every property of the aggregate where no event changes more than one property is perhaps the canonical example of an anemic domain model).  About the only reason I can see it making sense to apply the event handler in the command handler is a case where deciding that a given command is invalid would be effectively duplicating the event handler's logic and making the resulting state impossible to represent has an adverse effect on overall code clarity or is not easily expressible in your language's type system: sort of the "f around, find out, and then forget it ever happened" approach.  An example might be some domain constraint that the total cost of a valid order must never be an the product of an even number and a perfect square greater than 4 (so $18, $32, $36, $50, $54, $64, etc. are forbidden).